# Document distance algorithm with C++ vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm

Iam trying to build Document distance algorithm with C++ vectors, the algorithm is working fine the similiary vectors and give me output 0, which mean the vectors are same 100%, but when i try it with very difference strings it gaves me value like one point some decimals, the value should be 90 or nearby it when it difference, this is my code:

```
double dotProduct(vector <string> word1 , vector <string> word2) {

    double dotProductSum = 0;
    int  frequencyD1 = 0;
    int  frequencyD2 = 0;


    if (word1.size() > word2.size()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < word1.size(); i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < word1.size(); j++) {

                if (word1[i] == word1[j]) {

                    frequencyD1++;
                }

                if (word2[i] == word2[j]) {
                    frequencyD2++;
                }

            }

            dotProductSum += frequencyD1 * frequencyD2;
            frequencyD1 , frequencyD2 = 0;
        }

    }

    else {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < word2.size(); i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < word2.size(); j++) {

                
               if (word2[i] == word1[j]) {

                        frequencyD1++;
                }

                 if (word2[i] == word2[j]) {
                        frequencyD2++;
                    }

                }

            dotProductSum += frequencyD1 * frequencyD2;
            frequencyD1, frequencyD2 = 0;
        }
        
    }

    return dotProductSum;

}
```

**Test case:**

```
    vector <string> doc1 = { "this" , "is" , "cat" };
    vector <string> doc2 = { "Here" , "test" ,"two" };
    
    double normalization = dotProduct(doc1, doc2) / sqrt(dotProduct(doc1, doc1) * dotProduct(doc2, doc2)) ;

    cout << acos(normalization)  << endl;  // 1.5708
```

Comment: `if (word1.size() > word2.size())` In this case the `i, j` loops run for `j < word1.size()` and `if (word2[i] == word2[j])` will go out of the bounds of `word2` at some point. Same in the `else` part, so the posted code can only stay in-bounds if `word1.size() == word2.size()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `frequencyD1 , frequencyD2 = 0;`

This is a [comma operator expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) evaluated as `(frequencyD1) , (frequencyD2 = 0);` which is equivalent to `frequencyD2 = 0;` and leaves `frequencyD1` unchanged.

To reinitialize both variables to `0` use the following, instead.

```
   frequencyD1 = frequencyD2 = 0;
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Also...

> the value should be 90 or nearby it when it difference
>
>  ...
>
>  `cout << acos(normalization)  << endl;  // 1.5708`

...note that [acos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/acos) returns the angle in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), and `1.5708 ≈ π/2 = 90°`.

Comment: it gaves me "1.23096", Is that should be correct value for the test case in the question?

Comment: @YusufTaha This fixes one clear problem where the posted code went wrong. Whether the new result is correct depends on how exactly you define the "distance" and other unstated assumptions (such as, for example, the two vectors having the same size).